# 24VDC GPIO Inputs on Rasb Pi?

Tags: gpio, power

I want to use a raspberry pi to pick up some 24v DC inputs. I would ideally like to use an off the shelf module to add this functionality to my Pi (v3 model B).

I have come across this range of relay cards - http://denkovi.com/relay-cards-24v which feature circuits like this:

[image]

These are obviously intended for allowing the Raspberry Pi to drive 24V outputs. But could I could I use my 24V input as the Input and then have +5V on C and connect NO to the Raspberry Pi terminal?

Comment: Remember the Pi GPIO must not be exposed to more than 3V3.

Answer (score 4):

It would be simpler just to use a voltage divider to bring the 24v down to 3.3v for the Raspberry Pi or safer still use an optocoupler such as the 4N35 which is what I would use personally. Example circuits are on the 4N35 datasheet which is readily available.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f46tZi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: 4N35 Pinout]

4N35 Pinout

Comment: I can't seem to find any off the shelf modules which break out the Pi GPIO with opto-isolators

Comment: No you'd need to add the 2 resistors yourself, surely simple enough to do ?